# How to enable clock skew correction for AWS Lambda Function in iOS (bypass InvalidSignatureException)?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to enable clock skew correction for AWS Lambda Functions in iOS? I know clock skew correction is enabled in other AWS Services (ex: AWS UserPool and Cognito).

or is there a way to bypass the InvalidSignatureException?

Comment: Are you calling your Lambda functions directly via the AWS SDK? Or are you using API Gateway? In either case the clock skew handling should be a function of the API calls and not directly related to AWS Lambda. I would start by reading this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/clock-skew-fix/

Comment: I tried with API Gateway and direct calling AWS Lambda, both did not handle clock skew correction automatically. So what you mean is I need to catch the error in the API gateway and propagate it to the device or am I missing something?

Comment: You can try manually setting the clock skew with `[NSDate aws_setRuntimeClockSkew:NSTimeIntervalSince1970];` replacing with the correct time interval.